# When radio button is clicked, element content changes to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I can get it working for text, but can't enable it so it reads HTML for image - http://jsfiddle.net/BgQPF/

```
<p> Current Radiobutton Value = <span data-bind='text: selected' ></span></p>

<input type='radio' name='onlyOne' data-bind='checked: selected, enable: enable' value='<img src="https://github.com/gentoo90/minimal-django-file-upload-example/diff_blob/9ab39c7fe5abaf00f2d586e88e79a5a85075179e/src/for_django_1-3/myproject/media/documents/2012/07/12/example02.jpg?raw=true">' /> Yes
<input type='radio' name='onlyOne' data-bind='checked: selected, enable: enable' value='N' /> No
<input type='radio' name='onlyOne' data-bind='checked: selected, enable: enable' value='M' /> Maybe
```

Comment: you want the snap to contain an image?

Comment: you put the img tag inside the span tag, but you need to replace the span tag

Comment: So when you click 'Yes' an image appears instead of the text in the value="".

Comment: Chrome shows, in the console for your Fiddle: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ko is not defined`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

here is the deal

```
<span data-bind='html: selected' ></span>
```

instead of

```
<span data-bind='text: selected' ></span>
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9d8qc6kL/)**

Comment: OP wants to use image, see difference between our jsfiddle when changing radio button 'Yes'. OP at first set a wrong jsfiddle.

Comment: This is good, and i upvoted. However, I would like this opportunity to point out that it's never a good idea to put `<` and `>` in attribute values. Always use the entity references `&lt;` and `&gt;` (or of course, the numeric references `&#60;` and `&#62;`).

Answer (score 0):

And you are trying to output it to where?

On the exemple you gave, i get the correct value when pressing the first radio button, but why not to store the href only on the value and change the src attr of the img element, anted the radio button?

Html part:

```
<p> Current Radiobutton Value = <span data-bind='text: selected' ></span></p>

<img id="test_img" src='' alt="" width="32" height="32" />

<input type='radio' name='onlyOne' data-bind='checked: selected, enable: enable' value='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a118c92a699e7d003b8767a108d50f53?s=32&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG' /> Yes
<input type='radio' name='onlyOne' data-bind='checked: selected, enable: enable' value='N' /> No
<input type='radio' name='onlyOne' data-bind='checked: selected, enable: enable' value='M' /> Maybe

<BR/>

<input type='checkbox' data-bind='checked: enable'> Enable controls
```

script part:

```
var viewModel = {
    enable: ko.observable(true),
    selected: ko.observable('Y')
};


$('input[name="onlyOne"]').click(function (event) {
   $('#test_img').attr('src',$(this).val());
});

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Using the link example, crudly edited.

Regards,